# nginx-ingress pods keep crashing when request comes - AKS

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

our nginx-controller pods keep crashing when a request comes. From the logs, it looks like it has timeout connecting to API server, any idea how to enable more detailed logs?

[image]

```
I1213 14:55:35.038444       7 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://11.2.9.1:443/version?timeout=32s  in 46 milliseconds
I1213 14:55:35.038543       7 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I1213 14:55:35.038650       7 request.go:784] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 9 to https://11.2.9.1:443/version?timeout=32s
I1213 14:55:36.038955       7 round_trippers.go:419] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: nginx-ingress-controller/v0.0.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/$Format" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXRiWDII8dG8v-KJ90Av6HgE" 'https://11.2.9.1:443/version?timeout=32s'
I1213 14:55:36.088346       7 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://11.2.9.1:443/version?timeout=32s  in 49 milliseconds
I1213 14:55:36.088382       7 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I1213 14:55:36.088598       7 request.go:947] Response Body:
I1213 14:55:36.088730       7 main.go:212] Unexpected error discovering Kubernetes version (attempt 9): an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
F1213 14:55:36.088826       7 main.go:235] Error while initiating a connection to the Kubernetes API server. This could mean the cluster is misconfigured (e.g. it has invalid API server certificates or Service Accounts configuration). Reason: an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
Refer to the troubleshooting guide for more information: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/
```

when kubectl into the ingress pod, this is the log

```
C:\Users\XXXXX>kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-85d79fd99d-tlzrz -- /bin/bash
www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-85d79fd99d-tlzrz:/etc/nginx$ curl -k -v -XGET https://11.2.9.1:443/version?timeout=32s
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x56450f95cdd0)
*   Trying 11.2.9.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x56450f95cdd0)
* Connected to 11.2.9.1 (11.2.9.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 11.2.9.1:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 11.2.9.1:443
www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-85d79fd99d-tlzrz:/etc/nginx$
```

Answer (score 1):

it is due to network security policy enforced that does not allow the ingress node to ping API server by internal IP. Adding the env variable to the ingress controller deployment file to force it to use FQDN solves the issue.KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=FQDN of the API server

Comment: This is indeed the problem here! The curl trace shows it can connect to the API server, but then is terminated when the SNI (Server Name Indication) is sent.